# JDBC going to the wrong address

Tags: java, mysql

When I try and connect it my mysql database with JDBC in java, it doesn't go to my web server.

Here is the code

```
String dbtime;
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://184.172.176.18:3306/dcsoft_dcsoft_balloon";
String dbUser = "myuser";
String dcPass = "mypass";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "Select * FROM users";

try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dcPass);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        dbtime = rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(dbtime);
    } 

    con.close();

} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is supposed to go to my web server but it gives this error
   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'dcsoft_dcsoft_java'@'jamesposse.force9.co.uk' (using password: YES)

jamesposse.force9.co.uk is the not the address im trying to connect to I'm trying to connect to 184.172.176.18:3306.

Thanks.

---

The hosts file contents is -

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

and lmhosts is -

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample LMHOSTS file used by the Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to computernames
# (NetBIOS) names.  Each entry should be kept on an individual line.
# The IP address should be placed in the first column followed by the
# corresponding computername. The address and the computername
# should be separated by at least one space or tab. The "#" character
# is generally used to denote the start of a comment (see the exceptions
# below).
#
# This file is compatible with Microsoft LAN Manager 2.x TCP/IP lmhosts
# files and offers the following extensions:
#
#      #PRE
#      #DOM:<domain>
#      #INCLUDE <filename>
#      #BEGIN_ALTERNATE
#      #END_ALTERNATE
#      \0xnn (non-printing character support)
#
# Following any entry in the file with the characters "#PRE" will cause
# the entry to be preloaded into the name cache. By default, entries are
# not preloaded, but are parsed only after dynamic name resolution fails.
#
# Following an entry with the "#DOM:<domain>" tag will associate the
# entry with the domain specified by <domain>. This affects how the
# browser and logon services behave in TCP/IP environments. To preload
# the host name associated with #DOM entry, it is necessary to also add a
# #PRE to the line. The <domain> is always preloaded although it will not
# be shown when the name cache is viewed.
#
# Specifying "#INCLUDE <filename>" will force the RFC NetBIOS (NBT)
# software to seek the specified <filename> and parse it as if it were
# local. <filename> is generally a UNC-based name, allowing a
# centralized lmhosts file to be maintained on a server.
# It is ALWAYS necessary to provide a mapping for the IP address of the
# server prior to the #INCLUDE. This mapping must use the #PRE directive.
# In addtion the share "public" in the example below must be in the
# LanManServer list of "NullSessionShares" in order for client machines to
# be able to read the lmhosts file successfully. This key is under
# \machine\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\parameters\nullsessionshares
# in the registry. Simply add "public" to the list found there.
#
# The #BEGIN_ and #END_ALTERNATE keywords allow multiple #INCLUDE
# statements to be grouped together. Any single successful include
# will cause the group to succeed.
#
# Finally, non-printing characters can be embedded in mappings by
# first surrounding the NetBIOS name in quotations, then using the
# \0xnn notation to specify a hex value for a non-printing character.
#
# The following example illustrates all of these extensions:
#
# 102.54.94.97     rhino         #PRE #DOM:networking  #net group's DC
# 102.54.94.102    "appname  \0x14"                    #special app server
# 102.54.94.123    popular            #PRE             #source server
# 102.54.94.117    localsrv           #PRE             #needed for the include
#
# #BEGIN_ALTERNATE
# #INCLUDE \\localsrv\public\lmhosts
# #INCLUDE \\rhino\public\lmhosts
# #END_ALTERNATE
#
# In the above example, the "appname" server contains a special
# character in its name, the "popular" and "localsrv" server names are
# preloaded, and the "rhino" server name is specified so it can be used
# to later #INCLUDE a centrally maintained lmhosts file if the "localsrv"
# system is unavailable.
#
# Note that the whole file is parsed including comments on each lookup,
# so keeping the number of comments to a minimum will improve performance.
# Therefore it is not advisable to simply add lmhosts file entries onto the
# end of this file.
```

Comment: What is the contents of your `etc/hosts` file?

Comment: The hosts and lmhosts.sam file have nothing but hashes so the hosts files are empty.

Comment: the directory should be C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, right?

Comment: I added the contents in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jamesposse.force9.co.uk` is the machine that you're connecting from.

When MySQL complains `Access denied for user 'dcsoft_dcsoft_java'@'jamesposse.force9.co.uk'`, it means that the user `dcsoft_dcsof_java` was not authorized to connect from the host `jamesposse.force9.co.uk`.

In MySQL, you are authenticated by the username you try to connect to, and the hostname you're trying to connect from. This is why you grant access to users like:

```
grant access to 'dcsoft_dcsoft_java'@'localhost' identified by 'whatever'
```

This user can only connect from the same machine as the MySQL server (e.g. from webapps hosted on the same machine, or when you SSH into the machine and use the `mysql` commandline from there).

If you want to grant access to a specific machine, identify it by hostname or IP address.

```
grant access to 'dcsoft_dcsoft_java'@'184.172.176.18' identified by 'whatever'
```

To grant access from anywhere on the internet, use `'%'` as the host:

```
grant access to 'dcsoft_dcsoft_java'@'%' identified by 'whatever'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not entirely sure how to grant access is this something i would do in cpanel.

Comment: @DCSoft: I've never used cpanel, but I assume it must be possible.

Comment: well, in cpanel you have Remote Database Access Hosts and it says - You can allow external web servers to access your MySQL databases by adding their domain name to the list of hosts that are able to access databases on your web site.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a mysql on redhat password issue.  I'm not sure why it's not using the username you're providing it though, unless you're not actually using:

```
String dbUser = "myuser";
String dcPass = "mypass";
```

And using 
    dcsoft_dcsoft_java
as your username.
Can you give some more details on your environment?
In mysql make sure that you have whateverUserNameYourUsing@% otherwise, you'll get this error.  You can also replace the % with the IP address and/or domain name, but it has to be every domain name your database will allow access from.

Comment: He probably redacted the username in one place when posting his question, but forgot the other.

Comment: yeah, I removed it in one place but not the other.

Comment: That's my thought.  You never know though.